# Commencer une phrase par « à cela près » ?

Tags: grammaire

> Blabla [longue phrase]… je me retrouverai donc avec les mêmes difficultés. **À cela près** que ces difficultés ne seront pas liées cette fois-ci à ci, mais à ça.

Comment: Quelle est la question ?

Answer (score 2):

**Ceci** et **cela** ont une signification commune, mais, en fonction du contexte, on utilisera l'un ou l'autre.

Il y a grosso modo deux règles qui différencient l'usage de ces deux mots :

- **Ceci** fait référence à ce qui va arriver, qui n'est pas encore énoncé; alors que **cela** fait référence à quelque chose qui vient de se passer ou qui a été énoncé.
- **Ceci** fait référence à ce qui nous est proche, alors que **cela** fait référence à ce qui est plus éloigné, que ce soit dans l'espace ou dans le temps.

---

Pour répondre à ta question, la phrase n'est pas tout à fait correcte, elle ne respecte pas le premier point. Il y a deux façons de la corriger :

1. **Transformer "Cela" en "Ceci"**

> Blabla [longue phrase]… je me retrouverai donc avec les mêmes difficultés. À **ceci** près que ces difficultés ne seront pas liées cette fois-ci à ci, mais à ça.

2. **Inverser la structure**

Proposition avec ce que j'ai du texte :

> ... au final, les difficultés ne seront pas liées à ci, mais à ça. À **cela** près néanmoins, je me retrouve avec les mêmes [difficultés].

---

Post Scriptum :
Les règles sont similaires avec voici/voilà, ici/là, et d'autres couples __ci/__là que j'aurais oublié.